# Why reading a text file in lua returns only last chunk?

Tags: lua

I am trying to read a large file and return a table with word counts.
I found an example of efficient reading of large files on [lua.org](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.1.html) and came up with the final version of my little script.

```
function cnt_word(stream)
  local BUFSIZE = 2^13 -- 8KB
  local sin = io.input(stream) -- open input file
  local wc = {}
  local text = ""
  while true do
    local data, line = sin:read(BUFSIZE, '*l')
    if not data then break end
    if line then data = data .. line .. '\n' end
    text = data
  end
  -- creating a table with word counts
  for m in text:gmatch("%w+") do
    if not wc[m] then wc[m] = 0 end
    wc[m] = wc[m] + 1
  end
  return wc
end

input, word = arg[1], arg[2]
if not input then print("Error! Provide a valid filename") os.exit() end
if not word then print("Error! Provide a valid query term") os.exit() end
cnts = cnt_word(input)
cnt = cnts[word]
if not cnt then
  print(string.format("'%s' not found in '%s'", word, input))
  os.exit()
  end
print(string.format("'%s' cnt: %s", word, cnt))
```

The problem with this script is that it returns only the last ~70 lines of the file and I can't figure out why. Line concatenation `if line then data = data .. line .. '\n' end` is executed ~3k times which should be enough to collect the whole data inside `data` variable. However when I check the length of `data` inside the loop it is not growing but fluctuates around 8k, moreover when I check the length of `text` it is for some reason is ~3k. I do not understand what is Lua doing with the data and why it is doing it. Can somebody help me figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what your code is doing.

```
local data, line = sin:read(BUFSIZE, '*l')
```

You read X bytes of data, then up to the next endline.

```
if not data then break end
```

If no data was read, return.

```
if line then data = data .. line .. '\n' end
```

If `line` contains data, then concatenate it into the total.

```
text = data
```

So... what do you suppose that does? I know what it *doesn't* do. It doesn't *concatenate* the block of data with what was already loaded. It *replaces* whatever was in that variable already.

Which means the last thing that `text` stores... is the last block of data you loaded.

---

A word on efficiency.

What you read on Lua.org about efficiently loading large files is correct. But that code is written *assuming* that you are going to load a chunk, then *process* that chunk, then load another one.

What you're doing is loading the file chunk by chunk, then concatenating them (OK, you're *not* actually doing that, but that's what you wanted;) ), and then processing the whole file.

That's *not* efficient. If you want to load the whole file then process the entire thing when it is in mempry, that's what `read("*a")` is for.

Comment: I see, so basically what I have to do is `if line then text = text .. data .. line .. '\n' end` for this example to work.
I agree that I'd better use `read("*a")`, just wanted to try an example.

Comment: No, you should concatenate with `text` *regardless* of whether `line` is empty or not. Your assignment should become `text = text .. data`. And yes, you should just use `read("*a")`.

Comment: @minerals **If you are going to use the efficient reading method** then you should not be using `*a` **and you should not do** `text = text .. data` since that would be almost the same as reading the whole file in one go anyways. The point in reading full lines only is that you do not concatenate the whole result in the end before working on it but you still get the whole words. The efficiency gain is from never loading the whole file to memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code that does the word counting to be called inside the while loop after `text = data`.

What overall happens in the code is that the file is read in blocks size of `BUFSIZE`. Then that block should be processed and after that the block is replaced with the next block.
Because all your work is done after all the reading is done your word counting function only processes the last block it reads and not all of them.